# tkinter is taking a different master than given

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Toplevel widget which asks the User what widget he want to spawn and then asks for cnf. Whatfor and stuff is not important.

The cnf will be asked in an Scrollframe-Table-something (I don't really know how to describe it ^^'). Extra for that Scrollframe and its Scrollbar I made a Frame, so I can easily pack it left and right. But somehow the Scrollframe is taking the Tk window (root of my toplevel) as master.

Here is the code - I can't find my mistake:

```
from tkinter import _cnfmerge as cnfmerge
from tkinter import *
class Scrollframe(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,height=200,width=200,**kw):
        if 'yscrollcommand' in kw:
            self.ysc=kw['yscrollcommand']
            del kw['yscrollcommand']
        else: ysc=None
        if 'pad' in kw:
            self.pad=kw['pad']
            del kw['pad']
        else: self.pad=0
        Frame.__init__(self,height=height,width=width)
        self.scrollframe=Frame(self,**kw)
        self.scrollframe.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1)
        self.config(bg=self.scrollframe['bg'])
        self.bind('<Configure>',self.adopt)
        self.widgets,self.scrollable={},False
    def adopt(self,event=None):
        if self.scrollframe.winfo_height()>self.winfo_height():
            self.scrollable=True
            self.scrollframe.place(y=0)
            self.ysc(0,0)
        else:
            self.scrollable=False
            self.ysc(0,1)
    def addItem(self,widget=None,cnf={},**kw):
        if widget:
            cnf=cnfmerge((cnf,kw))
            if 'width' in cnf: del cnf['width']
            obj=widget(self.scrollframe,cnf)
            if len(self.widgets)==0 and self.pad!=0: obj.pack(fill=X)
            else: obj.pack(fill=X,pady=(self.pad,0))
            id_=str(id(obj))+widget.__name__
            obj.bind('<Destroy>',lambda event: self.delItem(id_),'+')
            self.widgets[id_]=obj
            return id_
    def getItem(self,id):
        return self.widgets[id]
    def delItem(self,id):
        try: self.widgets[id].destroy()
        except TclError: del self.widgets[id]
        except KeyError: pass 
    def yview(self,*args):
        try: delta=int(args[1])
        except ValueError: delta=float(args[1])
        maxnegscroll=self.winfo_height()-self.scrollframe.winfo_height()
        if isinstance(delta,float):
            if maxnegscroll<0: self.scrollframe.place(y=int(maxnegscroll*delta))
            delta=abs(int(self.scrollframe.place_info()['y'])/maxnegscroll)
            self.ysc(delta,delta)
        else:
            delta=-delta*3
            if int(self.scrollframe.place_info()['y'])+delta<maxnegscroll: self.scrollframe.place(y=maxnegscroll)
            elif int(self.scrollframe.place_info()['y'])+delta>0: self.scrollframe.place(y=0)
            else: self.scrollframe.place(y=int(self.scrollframe.place_info()['y'])+delta)
            delta=abs(int(self.scrollframe.place_info()['y'])/maxnegscroll)
            self.ysc(delta,delta)

class CreateWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,master,height=458,width=400)
        self.grab_set()
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.title('Neues Item')
        self.vars,self.cnf,self.cnfids={},{},{}

        cnf=create_dict(bg='gainsboro',width=380)
        Frame(self,cnf=cnf,height=39).place(x=10,y=10)
        Frame(self,cnf=cnf,height=103).place(x=10,y=59)
        Frame(self,cnf=cnf,height=220).place(x=10,y=172)
        bottom=Frame(self,cnf=cnf,height=46)
        bottom.pack_propagate(False)
        bottom.place(x=10,y=402)

        var,values,self.oldwidget=StringVar(value='Frame'),list(_tkinter_widgets.keys())[2:],'Frame'
        for i in range(len(values)): values[i]=values[i].__name__
        Spinbox(self,values=values,textvar=var,state=READONLY,cursor='arrow',command=self.refresh,buttonuprelief=FLAT,buttondownrelief=FLAT,wrap=True).place(x=20,y=20)
        self.vars['widget']=var

        Label(self,text='Höhe:',bg='gainsboro',anchor=W,bd=1).place(x=20,y=69)
        var=StringVar()
        Entry(self,textvar=var,justify=CENTER,width=40).place(x=136,y=69)
        self.vars['height']=var
        Label(self,text='Breite:',bg='gainsboro',anchor=W,bd=1).place(x=20,y=98)
        var=StringVar()
        Entry(self,textvar=var,justify=CENTER,width=40).place(x=136,y=98)
        self.vars['width']=var
        var=BooleanVar(value=True)
        Checkbutton(self,onvalue=True,offvalue=False,text='Farbe übernehmen (falls vorhanden)',variable=var,cursor='hand2',bg='gainsboro',activebackground='gainsboro').place(x=20,y=127)
        self.vars['takecolor']=var

        cnfsframe=Frame(self,height=200,width=360)
        cnfsframe.pack_propagate(0)
        cnfsframe.place(x=20,y=182)
        sb=Scrollbar(cnfsframe)
        sb.pack(fill=Y,side=RIGHT)
        self.cnfs=Scrollframe(master=cnfsframe,width=360-17,height=200,yscrollcommand=sb.set)
        self.cnfs.pack(fill=Y,side=LEFT)
        sb.config(command=self.cnfs.yview)
        for arg in _tkinter_widgets[Frame]:
            id=self.cnfs.addItem(Frame,height=19,width=360)
            obj=self.cnfs.getItem(id)
            var=StringVar()
            Entry(obj,width=35,justify=CENTER,textvar=var).place(x=146,y=0)
            Label(obj,text=arg,bd=1).place(x=0,y=0)
            self.cnf[arg],self.cnfids[arg]=var,id

        Button(bottom,text='Bestätigen',command=self.confirm,width=12,height=1).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
        Button(bottom,text='Abbrechen',command=self.destroy,width=12,height=1).pack(side=RIGHT,padx=(0,10),pady=10)
    def refresh(self):
        self.vars['height'].set(''),self.vars['width'].set(''),self.vars['takecolor'].set(True)
        for arg in _tkinter_widgets[eval(self.oldwidget)]:
            self.cnfs.delItem(self.cnfids[arg])
            del self.cnfids[arg],self.cnf[arg]
        for arg in _tkinter_widgets[eval(self.vars['widget'].get())]:
            id=self.cnfs.addItem(Frame,height=19,width=360)
            obj=self.cnfs.getItem(id)
            obj.pack_propagate(False)
            var=StringVar()
            Entry(obj,width=35,justify=CENTER,textvar=var).pack(side=RIGHT)
            Label(obj,text=arg,bd=1).pack(fill=X,side=LEFT)
            self.cnf[arg],self.cnfids[arg]=var,id
        self.oldwidget=self.vars['widget'].get()
        self.focus()
    def confirm(self):
        raise NotImplementedError #first I'll have to fix that scrollframe issue xD

if __name__=='__main__':
    t=Tk()
    cw=CreateWindow(t)
```

Before someone asks what self.scrollable in Scrollframe is for: Its for the MouseWheel binding I'll implement later.

Comment: please include your imports. There are several lines that are undefined variables.

Comment: @Mike-SMT What lines do you mean? I could understand if you don't get that cnfmerge but thats just tkinter _cnfmerge. The rest should be standard tkinter.

Comment: In my Eclipse IDE it is saying that `cnfmerge`, `_tkinter_widgets`, `READONLY` and  `create_dict` are all undefined. This may be due to your imports but I need to see them to know for sure. Keep in mind I added `from tkinter import *` to the top of your code just to try to test it. When you ask a question you always need to include the imports or else we are testing by guessing.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Hm yeah ok. I forgot about that. I added the imports. `_tkinter_widgets` is just an dict with all normal tkinter widgets and their keywordarguments. `READONLY` is just the string `'readonly'`. And finally `create_dict` should be kinda self explaining...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line, you are not passing the master to the super-class' `__init__`:

```
Frame.__init__(self,height=height,width=width)
```

Just change it to:

```
Frame.__init__(self,master=master, height=height,width=width)
```

That said, it is a general Python recommendation to use `super()` instead of hardcoding the superclass name:

```
super().__init__(master=master, height=height, width=width)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. Sometimes I'm just blind as hell... But why should I use super() here? There will be no other superclass then Frame. Or does it bring other advantages too?